# Write query string parameters to request with core http module

Tags: node.js, http

Regarding:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

How can we set the query string params with the options object?

```
  const opts = {
     hostname: 'localhost',
     path: '/',
     port: 6969
   };

  const req = http.get(opts, function(resp){

  });
```

I am guessing that we have to write them to the request stream? but how?

```
req.write(???);
```

this does not seem to be well documented. :(

With the user-land request package, it would be:

```
const request = require('request');
request.get({qs:{}});
```

**but I am looking to do this with the core module if possible, not the userland package.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well native http module is a bit limited when doing http requests you have better libs like (request or axios) but you can explicit set your query parameters.

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

```
  const value1 = 'hello'
  const value2 = 1234

  const opts = {
     hostname: 'localhost',
     path: `/?param1=${value1}&param2=${value2}`,
     port: 6969
   };

  const req = http.request(opts, function(resp){

  });
```

Comment: yeah thanks, it's pretty lame that it doesn't take another string param, and append that to path for you.

Comment: You are right, It's not the most beautiful interface for http requests but that's why people do other libs like request or axios :) if it helps mark as resolved!